# Automatic HTML Form Generation for Arbitrary Structure

Tags: html, forms

Is there something that will create an HTML form from an arbitrary object, recognizing appropriate element types, lists, etc. and produce a modified object when submitted? This looks close to what I'm thinking of but it has requirements on the object structure:

http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxForm/index.shtml

Comment: Without that object structure, how do you expect the tool to figure out what kind of input control to use? E.g. if there's a string in the object, should it be an input field or a choice in a menu, and how would it know all the menu choices?

Comment: I found one solution, but I'm not sure if they're providing the code for my use: http://www.alkemis.com/jsonEditor.htm

Comment: This one looks pretty nice https://github.com/wjosdejong/jsoneditoronline

Comment: @JoeBeuckman: What you're looking for is likely a: JSON to DHTMLXForm converter *or* DHTMLXForm generator